# Position sprite inside camera view

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to position a sprite, the problem is that I have a camera view and I can't figure a way out to center my sprite inside the view.
I tried to to something like this:

```
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: cameraNode.frame.midX, y: cameraNode.frame.midY)
```

to center the sprite in the screen. but it is not working. the sprite is not being centered.
This is the camera:

```
camera = cameraNode
camera?.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
```

the variable `cameraNode` is a simple `SKCameraNode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `frame` property isn't directly from `SKCameraNode`, its from its `SKNode` parent class and here is what it does (from Apple Developper documentation):

> The frame property provides the bounding rectangle for a node’s visual
>   content, modified by the scale and rotation properties.

A camera node doesn't draw any content, it is just a representation of a camera you can use as a point of view; therefore the `frame` property isn't useful here.

From the documentation:

> The scene is rendered so that the camera node’s origin is placed in
>   the middle of the scene.

**Therefore you should rather use the `position` property of your camera node to place your object as you want.**